# SDE two problems

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have to solve these two SDEs:
   $$dX_t=-\frac{1}{1+t}X_tdt+\frac{1}{1+t}dW_t $$
   $$dX_t=X_t^3dt+X_t^2dW_t $$
The notes that my professor gave me are pretty theoretic and they have no examples. The only lectures I had on SDE were today and the professor gave these problems for homework that is due tomorrow. Even if I pull an all-nighter I will have about 13-14 hours to learn brand new stuff from confusing notes and to solve these two problems, which is pretty much impossible for me. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A standard approach is the following: Assume for the moment being that the solution is of the form $$X_t = f(W_t)$$

for some nice function $f$. Applying Itô's formula gives

$$X_t-X_0 = f(W_t)-f(0) = \int_0^t f'(W_s) \, dW_s + \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t f''(W_s) \, ds. \tag{1} $$

Now if we are interested in solving the SDE

$$dX_t = X_t^2 \, dW_t + X_t^3 \, dt \tag{2}$$

this means that we would like to find a function $f$ satisfying

$$f'(y) = f(y)^2 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{2} f''(y) = f(y)^3. \tag{3}$$

(If $f$ satisfies both equations, you can plug them into $(1)$ and you will easily see that $X_t = f(W_t)$ satisfies $(2)$.) Solve first the equation $f'(y) = f(y)^2$ and then verify that the solution $f$ satisfies also the second ODE.

---

In order to solve the SDE

$$dX_t = - \frac{1}{1+t} X_t \, dt + \frac{1}{1+t} \, dW_t$$

we can use a similar approach; however (because of the time dependence of the coefficients) we have to use the more general Ansatz

$$X_t = g(t,W_t).$$

If you apply Itô's formula, you will see that we have to find a function $g$ satisfying

$$\partial_x g(t,x) = \frac{1}{1+t} \quad \text{and} \quad - \frac{1}{1+t} g(t,x) = \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx} g(t,x) + \partial_t g(t,x).$$

Solve first the equation on the left-hand side and then check whether the solution satisfies the ODE on the right hand side.

Answer (score 2):

For the first equation consider that
$$
d((1+t)X_t)=(1+t)dX_t+X_tdt
$$
for the second apply the Ito formula for $Y=f(X)=X^{-2}$. This should reduce the problems to easily integrable terms.